# Plotly.r & ggplot2: when clicking the legend in a plot made via ggplotly, it fails to update ranges and bar positions after cases are withdrawn

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

(Based on the "Add Lines" example found here: https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_histogram/. It is also similar to [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176403/plotly-ggplot-stacked-bar-chart-disappear-when-legend-is-clicked), which has no satisfactory anwser for me, since I need to use the `ggplot` features, [like being able to use log scale in the x-axis](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1844))

In a normal `plot_ly` plot, when some legend element is clicked, the plot is modified taking away all the cases matching that legend group. The following example illustrates this behaviour:

```
library(plotly)

gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}

set.seed(0)

df1 <- data.frame(
  cond = factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each=200)),
  rating = c(rnorm(200), rnorm(200, mean=.9))
  )

plot_ly(df1,
  x = ~rating,
  color = ~cond,
  colors = gg_color_hue(2)) %>% 
  add_histogram() %>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

The figures show the interactive plot before and after clicking on the groups of the legend:

[image]

Figure 1: Histogram made using `plot_ly`, as it is plotted initially.

[image]

Figure 2: Histogram made using `plot_ly`, with only the B cases (after the A in the legend was clicked). Note how both axis adjusted to the new range of values.

[image]

Figure 3: Histogram made using `plot_ly`, with only the A cases (B was clicked). Again, both axis adjusted to the new range of values.

However, this does not happen when the plot is created via `ggplot` + `ggplotly`. Here is an example (please, do not mind the change in labels and colors or in the shape of the histograms, since those are not the focus of this Q and I don't believe are relevant):

```
p <- ggplot(data = df1) +
  aes(x = rating, fill = cond) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 13)

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Figure 4: Histogram made using `ggplot` and `ggplotly`.

[image]

Figure 5: Histogram made using `ggplot` and `ggplotly`, now with only the B cases (A was clicked). Note that the axis remain unchanged this time.

[image]

Figure 6: Histogram made using `ggplot` and `ggplotly`, now with only the A cases (B was clicked). Clearly the most ridiculous plot of them all, since the bars simply remain in their original spot, which is not helpfull at all for a histogram.

As I said, this is not a very desirable behaviour and I do not know if there's something I can do to correct it. If someone knows what can I do about this, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: `plotly != ggplotly` If you want maximal control over your plotly visualizations you will need to stick to plotly. If you want to quickly adapt an existing ggplot to an interactive version with tooltips then ggplotly is a fantasticly good way to do that. But at the end of the day it is still just a really good port and if you want all of the features you need to stick to the source.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Nate. I'd like to do just that, but then I have another obstacle which is that there is an issue with log scale and histograms in plotly (link in first part of the Q).

Comment: I hear you and understand there will be trade offs. My general strategy is to use Shiny to build ggplots to convert to plotly objects, so I can do reactive data filters. Since both of these projects are open source, if you have strong need for a new feature consider opening a pull request.